# Google Map not loading unless element is inspected

Tags: codeigniter

Google Maps doesn't load. When I inspect element, it loads correctly. How can I resolve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below JavaScript to your front

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function(){
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); 
    });
});
```

When you inspect element, it will trigger resize event to show google map. You want to do the same thing when the google map idles(gray)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mind posting the code/function you've used to retrieve the location co-ordinates from the API ?

Edit : Hope you're using the [BIOSTALL](https://github.com/BIOSTALL/CodeIgniter-Google-Maps-V3-API-Library) library instead of writing the code from scratch!

Answer (score 0):

Please use below CSS on your page. map is not loading because you are using modal. i think there could be issue of CSS.

```
<style>
    .pac-container {
        background-color: #FFF;
        z-index: 20;
        position: fixed;
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
    }
    .modal{
        z-index: 20;   
    }
    .modal-backdrop{
        z-index: 10;        
    }​
</style>
```